# Displaying 3D images using tkinter scale widget (scale widget too slow). The program hangs

Tags: python, image, tkinter, display

Hi I am trying to display a 3d image present in a numpy array as sequence of images in tkinter gui.

I would like to change the image as I slide through the scale widget in the tkinter. The below program is working. But the scale widget gets stuck and program hangs after a while.

```
import SimpleITK as sitk 
import numpy as np 

import tkinter as Tkinter
from tkinter import Button,Scrollbar 
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
import numpy

class mainWindow():
    def __init__(self,img):

        self.img = img 

        self.pil_images = [] 

        for i in range(self.img.shape[0]):

            img_slice = self.img[i,:,:]

            im=Image.frombytes('L', (img_slice.shape[1],img_slice.shape[0]), img_slice.astype('b').tostring())
            self.pil_images.append(im)

        slices, im_height, im_width = img.shape

        margin_width = 30
        margin_height = 30

        self.root = Tkinter.Tk()
        self.frame = Tkinter.Frame(self.root, width=im_width + margin_width*2, height=im_height + margin_height*2)
        self.frame.pack()

        self.sliderv1 = Tkinter.Scale(self.frame, orient= Tkinter.VERTICAL, from_= np.min(self.img), to= np.max(self.img), length = im_height)
        self.sliderv1.set(np.min(self.img))
        self.sliderv2 = Tkinter.Scale(self.frame, orient= Tkinter.VERTICAL, from_= np.min(self.img), to= np.max(self.img), length = im_height)
        self.sliderv2.set(np.max(self.img))

        self.canvas = Tkinter.Canvas(self.frame, width=im_width,height=im_height)

        self.sliderh = Tkinter.Scale(self.frame, orient= Tkinter.HORIZONTAL, 
            from_= np.min(self.img), to= np.max(self.img), length = im_width, 
            command=self.update_slice,repeatdelay = 1, resolution =  1)

        self.sliderv1.pack(side = Tkinter.LEFT)
        self.sliderv2.pack(side = Tkinter.LEFT)
        self.canvas.pack()
        self.sliderh.pack(side = Tkinter.BOTTOM)

        self.update_slice(0)

    def draw_image(self,slice):

        slice = int(slice)
        photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image=self.pil_images[slice])

        self.canvas.delete("IMG")
        self.canvas.create_image(0,0,image=photo,anchor=Tkinter.NW)
        self.root.update()
        self.root.mainloop()

    def update_slice(self,val):
        slice = val
        self.draw_image(slice)

if __name__ == "__main__":

    image = sitk.ReadImage("filepath")
    im_arr = sitk.GetArrayFromImage(image)
    mainWindow(im_arr)
```

Comment: This is not a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve); the imports and a data sample are missing to make the problem reproducible.

Comment: @Mr.T Sorry for that.  I have edited the question now.

Comment: @Amogh is it working as I wanted to use it